# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();. I am getting issue in refreshing token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Class-MyFirebaseIdService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String refreshToken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (firebaseUser !=null)
        {
            updateToken(refreshToken);
        }
    }

    private void updateToken(String refreshToken)
    {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Token token=new Token(refreshToken);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(token);
    }

}
```

Class-Chatfragment.java

```
private void UpdateToken() {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Token token = new Token(refreshToken);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(token);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact error (and stack trace) you're getting.

Comment: "I am getting issue in refreshing" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. Please add to your question what Frank van Puffelen asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated long ago. So it will not work anymore. Use `FirebaseMessagingService` and override the `onNewToken` method which will provide you new token as well. So use it as follows

```
public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   @Override
   public void onNewToken(String token) {          
        updateToken(token);
       
    }

    private void updateToken(String refreshToken)
    {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Token token=new Token(refreshToken);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(token);
    }

}
```

For the latest version of Firebase messaging visit [Latest SDK versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions)

Hope It works for you.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh but in Class-chatfragment i am getting issue because i can't write anything between Updatetoken() brackets. can you solve chat-fragment problem